# Audio shortcuts stopped working in Clementine

Tags: 11.10, shortcuts

I've upgraded my ubuntu to Oneric and my audio shortcuts are blocked. I use clementine and before upgrading everything works fine. But now, once I want to use my shortcuts a huge blocked sign appear in my screen.

[image: block]

Comment: I've never seen that before. It doesn't appear to be an Ubuntu notification. Does it happen in other applications, or just that one?

Comment: thanks jo for your answer.. well after read your comment I download Banshee and it works correctly... perhaps it is a clementine problem..

Answer (score 1):

[Check this out.](http://www.pauljoyceuk.com/codex/2011/clementine-shortcuts-not-working-in-ocelot-11-10/)

You need to disable the gnome shortcuts for these features...

> "Then its under “Shortcuts > Sound and Media“. The only way I managed
>   to get the conflict resolved was to clear the Gnome shortcuts by
>   pressing backspace when it says “new shortcut…”, then entering my old
>   Clementine shortcuts back in Clementine’s properties menu."